# Scipy Non-central Chi-Squared Random Variable

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Consider a sum of `n` squared iid normal random variables `S = sum (Z^2(mu, sig^2))`.  According to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/89779/sum-of-squares-of-normal-distributions), `S / sig^2` has a [noncentral chi-squared distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution) with degrees of freedom = `n` and non-centrality parameter = `n*mu^2`.

However, compare generating `N` of these variables `S` by summing squared normals with generating `N` noncentral chi-squared random variables directly using `scipy.ncx2`:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import ncx2, chi2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 1000  # number of normals in sum
N_MC = 100000  # number of trials

mu = 0.05
sig = 0.3

### Generate sums of squared normals ###
Z = np.random.normal(loc=mu, scale=sig, size=(N_MC, n))
S = np.sum(Z**2, axis=1)

### Generate non-central chi2 RVs directly ###
dof = n
non_centrality = n*mu**2
NCX2 = sig**2 * ncx2.rvs(dof, non_centrality, size=N_MC)
# NCX2 = sig**2 * chi2.rvs(dof, size=N_MC)  # for mu = 0.0

### Plot histos ###
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.hist(S, bins=50, label='S')
ax.hist(NCX2, bins=50, label='NCX2', alpha=0.7)
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

This results in the histograms
[image: comparison of distros]

I believe the mathematics is correct; could the discrepancy be a bug in the `ncx2` implementation?  Setting `mu = 0` and using `scipy.chi2` looks much better:
[image: distros good]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the second sentence of the question: *"`S / sig^2` has a noncentral chi-squared distribution with degrees of freedom = `n` and non-centrality parameter = `n*mu^2`."*  That non-centrality parameter is not correct.  It should be `n*(mu/sig)^2`.

The standard definition of the noncentral chi-squared distribution is that it is the sum of the squares of normal variates that have mean mu and *standard deviation 1*.  You are computing `S` using normal variates with standard deviation `sig`.  Let's write that distribution as `N(mu, sig**2)`.  By using the location-scale properties of the normal distribution, we have

```
N(mu, sig**2) = mu + sig*N(0, 1) = sig*(mu/sig + N(0,1)) = sig*N(mu/sig, 1)
```

So summing the squares of variates from `N(mu, sig**2)` is equivalent to summing the squares of `sig*N(mu/sig, 1)`.  That gives `sig**2` times a noncentral chi-squared variate with noncentrality `mu/sig`.

If you change the line where `non_centrality` is computed to

```
non_centrality = n*(mu/sig)**2
```

the histograms line up as you expect.

Comment: That seems to help.  Would you mind elaborating a bit?

Comment: I added some elaboration.